# Do website and app development require different developers?

Tags: ios, mobile, methodology

I am currently looking for a developer for a personal project that would require building both a new website and an application.

The application will allow users working from full sized PC's and laptops to help troubleshoot the problems of other users working in the field from mobile devices. The application and the website will therefore, at least initially, share identical functionality which is simply given a different user interface depending on the device.

Later stages of the project will focus on greatly expanding the website, but only making relatively minor updates to the application. In terms of approaching the project I would be really grateful for recommendations and answers on the following:

1. When developing apps that have shared functionality with a website does the website functionality need to be built first and then 'fit' onto the mobile platform, vice versa, or does each platform require its own development from the ground up?
2. Would the website and the app both require their own individual developers, or is it acceptable to have a single developer do both?
3. Are both the above completely subjective depending on what the project?

Comment: The answer to all three is "it depends".

Comment: Although I kind of knew the answer to that was something similar I was hoping some experienced developer might be able to guide me somewhat, like MMM has with mentioning a Web App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered building a web app?

A web app is essentially an HTML/Javascript web site which can be loaded on a phone an behaves like an app. Thus, you can have a "mobile version" of your website without the need of building a bespoke app (and saving money). Users can even save shortcuts to your website on their phones, so they can load it as any other app (you can even configure the website in such a way that whilst viewing it you get rid of the address bar and toolbar).

There are a lot of things that you can access via a web app, including:

- GPS
- Accelerometer
- Multi-touch gestures
- etc.

Therefore usually there is no need to create a bespoke iOS app, unless you need to access such things like the microphone, video-camera or store things on the phone.

This would mean that you can have one developer (or one developer team) who would build the website and its mobile, "web-app" version.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response. I had not until now considered a WebApp although you are right it may definitely be an alternative route. I have actually already got a spec for the app side of things and a rough brief for the website, I'm thinking now what may be an obstacle to a 'WebApp'. The application itself is very similar to a chat room type client i.e. mobile users will need to be able to joing chat rooms that also have active desktop/laptop users.  Does that sound possible with a webapp?

Comment: Indeed it does, recently iOS has been updated so that Mobile Safari now supports HTML5 WebSockets (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), a technology that enables you to create server-client style applications (the website basically establishes a real connection with a server, thus you can easily build a fully functioning chatroom).

Comment: Thanks again MMM, very helpful. A couple of last questions if you do not mind. Do you know of any websites that have resources for non-developers to try and research these technologies or the basics of webapp/app development. Two, do Web Apps allow for caching of content so that is available offline, this is a feature of my app? Some developer friends have recommended SCALA for the website technology but I  would assume this decision should really only be made by the active developer, no?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't visited any website that would explain everything when it comes to web apps, but what I would suggest is googling "html5 webapp", "webapp ios", "html5 ios" etc.. Web Apps can use a thing called "Local storage" (http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp) if you really want to cache some content on the device, although if it isn't a lot of content you can always just access it from the server. I am not familiar with SCALA but I do agree that the developer should choose the platform/language he wants to use for a particular project.

Comment: Q. >> "Two, do Web Apps allow for caching of content so that is available offline, this is a feature of my app? " A. Yes, several : http://code.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage.html " Offline APIs

App Cache
File System
IndexedDB
WebSQL (deprecated) "

Comment: mastDrinkNimbuPani, please keep in mind that many of those technologies you've mentioned are not supported by iOS and other mobile platforms.